# What is known about the PDFs for the $\ell^2$-norm of these multivariate distributions?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, norms, online-resources

I'm looking for resources giving the PDFs for the $\ell^2$-norm of various spherically symmetric, continuous multivariate distributions.

For instance, the PDF for the $\ell^2$-norm of a multivariate standard normal distribution can be shown to be the chi distribution. I'm looking for similar results regarding any or all of the following multivariate distributions (found [here](http://aurelie.boisbunon.free.fr/downloads/loisSS.pdf) on pp. 4-5):

- Kotz
- Student
- Exponential
- Logistic
- Laplace
- Bessel

Thank you.

*Note: I asked [this question over at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191166/the-probability-of-a-given-length-of-a-vector-drawn-from-a-multivariate-distribu), but it received practically no attention. Do let me know if this is off-topic, as this is my first post here.*

Comment: you only asked yesterday on MSE, one is typically advised to wait a week or so before crossposting...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you, will do for future posts.

Comment: You wrote "the PDF for the $\ell^2$-norm of a multivariate normal distribution with zero mean can be shown to be the chi distribution". Can it? What if it's a bivariate normal distribution with variance $\left[\begin{array}{r} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array} \right]\text{ ?}$ What you say is certainly true if the components in orthogonal directions are uncorrelated and all have variance $1$, and if they are uncorrelated and all have equal variances then it's just a constant times a chi-square random variable. But bivariate normal in general?

Comment: WAIT!! I just realized no generality is lost by assuming zero correlation, but the question of unequal variances is still there.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Ah, it seems that it is indeed only true for *standard* normal distributions, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a spherically symmetric distribution $P(\vec{x})=f(y)$ of an $n$-dimensional vector $\vec{x}$, of length $y=|\vec{x}|$, then the distribution $P(u)$ of the $\ell^2$-norm $u=|\vec{x}|^2=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ is just

$$P(u)\propto \frac{1}{u} u^{n/2}\,f(\sqrt{u}),$$

omitting a normalization constant. So for the six distributions you list one finds:

- Kotz: $f(y)\propto y^{2N-2}e^{-ry^2/\sigma^2} \Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{N-2+n/2}e^{-ru/\sigma^2}$
- Student: $f(y)\propto\left(1+\frac{y^2}{\nu\sigma^2}\right)^{-(\nu+n)/2}\Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{n/2-1}\left(1+\frac{u}{\nu\sigma^2}\right)^{-(\nu+n)/2}$
- Exponential: $f(y)=e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^{2b}/\sigma^{2b}} \Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{n/2-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^{b}/\sigma^{2b}}$
- Logistic: $f(y)\propto e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2/\sigma^2}\left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{2}y^2/\sigma^2}\right)^2\Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{n/2-1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}u/\sigma^2}\left(1+e^{-\frac{1}{2}u/\sigma^2}\right)^2$
- Laplace: $f(y)\propto K_0(\sqrt{2}y/\sigma)\Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{n/2-1}K_0(\sqrt{2u}/\sigma)$
- Bessel: $f(y)\propto y^q I_q(y/r)\Rightarrow P(u)\propto u^{(n+q)/2-1}I_0(u^{1/2}/r)$

I have omitted all normalization constants for brevity. Some of these distributions have names, a Gamma distribution for the first and third on your list, a Fisher distribution for the second, no name I know of for the last three.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Actually the paper you cited presented majority of the results that are known currently, a possible supplement is [1]. I will approach this problem by explaining the involvement of spherically symmetric distributions in statistics.

Spherically symmetric distributions are usually used to modeled covariance matrices of spatial processes in **spatial statistics**. In this regard, you may want to look at [5]. However, due to the increasing concern of non-stationarity of the covariance structure, this method of modeling is out-dated but still useful when the major concern is analysis of local spatial features as well as robustness of the process.

Spherically symmetric distributions are also useful in **statistical mechanics**[2] and therefore some analysis of classical ensembles. In this regard, you can refer to [3], whose formalism is basically on Hilbert spaces and hence not particularly hard to understand(at least for me...).

In recent years(started from 1980s)[6], another growing branch of statistics that makes intense use of the spherically symmetric distribution is the **directional statistics**(Or some people call it statistical shape analysis). One example is the Fisher distribution on a sphere; another example is the projected normal distribution [4], which is particularly useful when the data is indeed embedded into a sphere.

**Reference**

[1]Serfling, Robert J. "Multivariate symmetry and asymmetry." Encyclopedia of statistical sciences (2006).

[2]http://www.df.unipi.it/~konishi/SymmetryStatistics.pdf

[3]Von Neumann, John. Mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics. No. 2. Princeton university press, 1955.

[4]https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263896/moment-mgf-of-cosine-of-directional-vectors

[5]Gelfand, Alan E., et al., eds. Handbook of spatial statistics. CRC press, 2010.

[6]Mardia, Kanti V., and Peter E. Jupp. Directional statistics. Vol. 494. John Wiley & Sons, 2009.

[7]Jupp, P. E., and K. V. Mardia. "A unified view of the theory of directional statistics, 1975-1988." International Statistical Review/Revue Internationale de Statistique (1989): 261-294.